# How to manually convert an iPhone-only app to Universal in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode5, ios-universal-app

I have an iPhone-only app which needs to become universal. I selected the target and changed Deployment Info > Devices from "iPhone" to "Universal". The [blog post](http://blog.aaron-milam.com/2012/09/converting-your-iphone-app-to-universal.html) I found says Xcode asks you what to do. But it didn't ask anything. When I run the app on iPad it just crashes with no log in console.

The problem can be that my project doesn't use any xib files. Is there a resource that details what exactly you need to configure to make an app universal by hand?

Comment: What does the error says?, Can you share it?

Comment: I didn't get any errors. Just crash without any log. After several clean target and rebuilds it started working on iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making your App Universal:

- In Targets -> General -> Deployment Info -> Set Devices to Universal
- Now create iPad XIBs for the page that you have created.
- Select xib -> Go to File's Owner -> Choose Custom class tab in inspector -> Set the class name for which you have created the iPad xib
- Now select the view of that xib & go to inspector -> Set Referencing Outlets for the view

After following these steps while you run the Application into iPad than iPad screen will be opened without any crash.

Please note that you need to follow the steps every time when you create new iPad xib.